# Find all devices connected in a wifi network

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to make an app here, which will detect all the devices connected in that WiFi network. I have done enough google and come up with an [App](https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery) which can detect IP Addresses of the devices connected in the WiFi network of the app.

Now I want few more things.

1. Can I find device name i.e. phone name or model or system name any
   information by which we can detect the particular device?
2. Can we find the device distance like how far is that device from the
   phone in which we are using our app?
3. This one is the **main task**- I want to share data over device
   connected to same WiFi. So is that possible?

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Are you going to run your app on the Android device acting as WiFi hot spot or on an Android device connected to a hot spot ?

Comment: Is there any kind of server you are using?

Comment: @Cheeta No, but why server?

Comment: @user1721904 I am using my app on a device which is connected to a WiFi network.

Comment: So when you say IP addresses, you mean IP addresses of devices connected to the hot spot right ?

Comment: No IP address of the devices in the WiFi network which you are connected to.

Comment: IP addresses of device connected to a common access point in one WiFi network?

Comment: @user1721904 suppose you are connected to a wifi name"Abc". Now I want all the devices name in that "Abc" network. I am able to get IP address but not name.

Answer (score 4):

to identify device NMAP OS fingerprint can be run.

I want to share data between two device that is connected to same WiFi network. So is that possible?

What you mean by this ? if they are on same LAN they can communicate over socket connection provided client is listening on particular port.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get device name or model number using like this...

```
public String getDeviceName() {
  String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
  String model = Build.MODEL;
  if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
    return capitalize(model);
  } else {
    return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
  }
}


private String capitalize(String s) {
  if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
    return "";
  }
  char first = s.charAt(0);
  if (Character.isUpperCase(first)) {
    return s;
  } else {
    return Character.toUpperCase(first) + s.substring(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any idea about remaining two points ?

Comment: i cant understand 2nd point. but in 3rd point, you should application which make your phone hotspot. so that you can transfer data.

Comment: I am not able to understand your point here, though i tried WiFi direct also, but it doesn't address my problem, because it doesnt work on wifi. and as per my knowledge wi-fi hotspot allows us to share internet not data files.

Comment: i have dnt knw application name. but some app. there which provides transfering data.

Comment: Ok, i'll look for the apps,  but i din't find any.